# EXCEL: Nested If Statement with numbers AND text matching

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

What I want my logic to say:

> If a value in column "A" is greater than another cell value (A3), and a value in column C includes the string "non-toil", then add a count for all of the rows that satisfy these conditions.

The code I have in my cell is:

```
=IF(RawData!A1:A2000,<A3, COUNTIF(RawData!C1:C2000, "*non-toil*",))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(RawData!A1:A2000,"<" & A3,RawData!C1:C2000, "*non-toil*")
```